# How to get rid of white space on right of div?

Tags: html, css

### What is happening

[image]

### What I want

As you can see, there is this pesky white space on the right side of `#Demo-Card` even though I set the `body{padding: 0; margin: 0;}`.

I also tried:

```
#Demo-Card {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
```

But that didn't work.

How do I get rid of this pesky white space?

If anyone could help w/ this it would be greatly appreciated!

### Code

*HTML*

```
<body>
<div id="Demo-Card">
    <header>
        <h3><span class="problem-number">11</span> <span class="problem-equation">Problem</span></h3> 
    </header>
    <!--<button id="Run">Run Demo</button>-->
    <div class="iframe-container">
        <iframe id="Demo-iFrame" src="mathsynthesis/LearningByExample/GUI/web/mathsynth.html">
            <p>Your browswer does not support iFrames</p>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

*CSS*

```
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*DEMO-CARD FORMATTING*/
#Demo-Card {
    width: calc(100vw - 40px);
    height: calc(100vh - 40px - 50px); /*40px for borders, 50px for menu*/
    background-color: white;
    border: 20px solid #86E1D8;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ostqbcyw/)

Comment: Yeah the answers are correct.. setting the width to 100vw or 100% works, I don't know why I thought border is applied to the width.. when I answered your question yesterday I was out of it. Sorry haha.

Comment: @zsawaf that's okay! Still, your answer was really helpful & I appreciated it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the div with the id `Demo-Card` you have this CSS set:

`width: calc(100vw - 40px);`

Which is equivalent to the total width of the browser window, minus 40px.

Instead, set this to:

`width: 100%;`

And it should work.

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. What is the problem and how does this solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't subtract 40px from the width of the `#Demo-Card`. Those 40px are creating that gap.

```
#Demo-Card {
    width: 100vw;
    height: calc(100vh - 40px - 50px); /*40px for borders, 50px for menu*/
    background-color: white;
    border: 20px solid #86E1D8;
}
```